# bash command splitting elements of xpath

Tags: shell, xpath

I'm searching for some linux shell command that help me to examine the elements of an XPath.
For example, given:

```
/a[@e=2]/bee/cee[@e<9]/@dee
```

I would need three commands returning, respectively:

```
a
[@e=2]
/bee/cee[@e<9]/@dee
```

Later I can repeat the process, in order to analyse all the Xpath.

I have tried using **sed** and regular expressions, but I was not able.

Comment: Why are you splitting it up this way?  Why not `a[@e=2]`, `bee`, `cee[@e<9]`, `@dee`? What are you trying to accomplish?  Why are you trying to do this a shell script -- why not a higher level language like Ruby or Python, which might be better suited to this sort of thing?

Comment: did you search here? `[linux] [xml]` yields 103, `[sed] [xml]` yields ~30, etc ... Better yet, search for `[xmlstarlet]`. Good luck.

Comment: @larsks: you are right, however, I faced the problem when I was already in the middle of a bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange request ... but you can do this pretty easily with `sed` with the pattern `^/\([-a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)\(\[[^]]*\]\)\(.*\)$`.  The segments that you requested are the three captures.

```
zsh% data='/a[@e=2]/bee/cee[@e<9]/@dee'
zsh% pattern='^/\([-a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)\(\[[^]]*\]\)\(.*\)$'
zsh% sed "s#$pattern#\1#" <($data)
a
zsh% sed "s#$pattern#\2#" <($data)
[@e=2]
zsh% sed "s#$pattern#\3#" <($data)
/bee/cee[@e<9]/@dee
zsh%
```

The pattern is very much specialized for the request.  XPath expressions are pretty difficult to rip apart in shell - both cumbersome and expensive.  Depending one what you are trying to accomplish, you would probably be better off translating the shell script into either Python, Ruby, or Perl depending on language preference.  You might also want to  take a look at using [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net) instead of Bash.  I've found it to be much more capable for advanced scripting.

Comment: Beautiful! It works! In my configuration, your redirections do not work, I used:
echo $data|sed "s#$pattern#\1#"

Comment: The redirects are zsh syntax so you have to do the `echo $data | sed` trick with bash.

Comment: considering that in xpaths the [...] part is not compulsory, and that node names can contain other symbols than letters and numbers, this is an improved pattern: `'^/\([^/\[]*\)\(\[[^]]*\]\)\?\(.*\)$'`